# Replacing colour of an Image

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, ocr, colormatrix

I am trying to replace the black colours of a picture with white, and vice versa. This is actually so my OCR code can read it on white backgrounds better. It's currently getting the image from clipboard

```
 Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
 pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
 pictureBox1.Image = img;
```

I've seen some other questions where they're working with an actual bitmap, but how do I approach it direct from Clipboard?

Comment: Is the incoming image literally black and white or might there be greys or other (subtle) colours included? If so, how would you want those dealt with?

Comment: is this black&white image?

Comment: Ehh, I doubt the image is pure black and white, because then replacing one of the colours would create a blank image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using the [ColorMatrix](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.colormatrix) class.

You can use the [Graphics.DrawImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage) overload that accepts an [ImageAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes) argument.
[`ImageAttributes.SetColorMatrix()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes.setcolormatrix) sets the color-adjustment matrix, optionally targeting a specific category (Bitmap, Pen, Brush etc.) and can be instructed to skip the Gray Colors, modify the Gray colors only or all Colors.

The [`ImageAttributes.SetThreshold()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageattributes.setthreshold) method allows to regulate the Colors cutoff point (threshold) to fine tune the Brightness.
It accepts values from `0` to `1`.
When set to `0`, an image is all white, all black when set to `1` (see the Docs about it).

Also consider that the "Inversion" depends on the original bitmap color pattern, so try different approaches. Sometimes, inverting the brightness can give you a better result, sometime it doesn't.

You OCR must be "trained", to verify what values suits it better.

Take a look at these articles:
[Recoloring (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533809(v=vs.85).aspx)
[ASCII Art Generator (CodeProject)](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10949/ASCII-Art-Generator)

**Brightness Matrix**:
`R=Red  G=Green  B=Blue  A=Alpha Channel  W=White (Brightness)`

Modify the Brightness component to obtain an "Inversion"

```
    R  G  B  A  W
R  [1  0  0  0  0]
G  [0  1  0  0  0]
B  [0  0  1  0  0]
A  [0  0  0  1  0]
W  [b  b  b  0  1]    <= Brightness
```

---

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

// ...

Image colorImage = Clipboard.GetImage();
// Default values, no inversion, no threshold adjustment
var bmpBlackWhite = BitmapToBlackAndWhite(colorImage);
// Inverted, use threshold adjustment set to .75f
var bmpBlackWhite = BitmapToBlackAndWhite(colorImage, true, true, .75f);

// ...

private Bitmap BitmapToBlackAndWhite(Image image, bool invert = false, bool useThreshold = false, float threshold = .5f)
{
    var mxBlackWhiteInverted = new float[][]
    {
        new float[] { -1, -1, -1,  0,  0},
        new float[] { -1, -1, -1,  0,  0},
        new float[] { -1, -1, -1,  0,  0},
        new float[] {  0,  0,  0,  1,  0},
        new float[] {  1,  1,  1,  0,  1}
    };

    var mxBlackWhite = new float[][]
    {
        new float[] { 1,  1,  1,  0,  0},
        new float[] { 1,  1,  1,  0,  0},
        new float[] { 1,  1,  1,  0,  0},
        new float[] { 0,  0,  0,  1,  0},
        new float[] {-1, -1, -1,  0,  1}
    };

    var bitmap = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
    using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    using (var attributes = new ImageAttributes()) {

        attributes.SetColorMatrix(new ColorMatrix(invert ? mxBlackWhiteInverted : mxBlackWhite));
        // Adjust the threshold as needed
        if (useThreshold) attributes.SetThreshold(threshold);
        var rect = new Rectangle(Point.Empty, image.Size);
        g.DrawImage(image, rect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ColorMap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.colormap(v=vs.110).aspx) and [ImageAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h9aaxdk(v=vs.110).aspx) classes from the `System.Drawimg.Imaging` namespace to directly replace the pixels in your image:

```
Image img = Clipboard.GetImage();
if (img != null) {
  ColorMap[] cm = new ColorMap[1];
  cm[0] = new ColorMap();
  cm[0].OldColor = Color.Black;
  cm[0].NewColor = Color.White;
  ImageAttributes ia = new ImageAttributes();
  ia.SetRemapTable(cm);
  using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img)) {
    g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, img.Size), 0, 0, img.Width, img.Height,
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel, ia);
  }
  pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
  pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Comment: Would it be worth disposing the previous `pictureBox1` image? Will this code also map white to black?

Comment: @mjwills Yes it would.  To switch white to black, just change the OldColor and NewColor values.

Answer (score 0):

if your image is B&W, it is very easy in [OpenCV](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp):

```
// bmp is your bitmap
var inverted = (255 - bitmap.ToMat()).ToMat().
  .ToBitamp() // or
  .ToWriteableBitmap() // or
  .ToBitmapSource()
```

OpenCV can be a little overkill if this in your only manipulation in the whole app