# Convert Any Image to ASCII Text

Tags: vb.net

This has been particularly difficult and annoying to research given the fondness of "ASCII ART".  That is **NOT** what I am trying to do here.  I need to replicate a process from an old software package that basically converts an image, any image, into ASCII text before sending it to a printer.  Here is an example of what it spits out...

[image: ascii image]

The first two lines are commands.  The next 315 lines are pure ASCII (well they call it ASCII but its obviously hex, (80 chars ber line), followed by several more commands and setup before executing the print.

I've written all the software already, with exception to converting the image to ascii.  Originally, and according to the documentation, the printer should accept raw binary data of several image types.  Well, after fighting with that for the past day, I now realize why the manufacturer themselves don't go down that road.

So, my question is, how best to go about converting an image to ascii (hex) characters to send to the printer?  My first guess would be to iterate through each character and convert it but that also seems like the slowest approach.

```
Public Shared Sub ConvertImageHex(filepath As String)
    Dim f_convOutBytes() As Byte = File.ReadAllBytes(filepath)
    Dim totalStreamLength As Int32 = f_convOutBytes.Length
    Dim labelOutStream(totalStreamLength) As Byte
    f_convOutBytes.CopyTo(labelOutStream, 0)
    Dim HexValue As String = String.Empty

    Dim labelPath As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath & "testasci.lbl"
    If File.Exists(labelPath) Then
        File.Delete(labelPath)
    End If
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(labelPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    Dim s As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fs)
    s.Close()
    fs.Close()
    fs = New FileStream(labelPath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
    s = New StreamWriter(fs)

    Dim i As Int32 = 0
    For Each c In f_convOutBytes
        i += 1
        If i > 38 Then
            s.Write(vbCrLf)
            i = 0
        End If
        HexValue = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(c), 16)
        s.Write(HexValue)
    Next
    s.Close()
    fs.Close()
    If Not s Is Nothing Then s = Nothing
    If Not fs Is Nothing Then fs = Nothing
End Sub
```

[image]

Quotes from the docs (Probably too much into the weeds at this point):

```
d = download data
type = the type of data that will follow, using standard file name extensions
ASC - Graphic in ASCII format

ASCII graphics
ASCII-Graphic format
The stucture is similar to the IMG format, but uses only ASCII characters, to enable a easy usage for
host devices or ERP systems.
Following rules are used:
• all data are hex bytes, i.e. 0-9 and a-f or A-F
• The printer waits for data until the defined picture size is received.
• Spaces and carriage returns can be added on different locations. It is required that a
carriage return is sent at the end of the picture data.
• The image data can be compressed with a simple algorithm which is black/white
optimized.
• The image data are transmitted from top to bottom, each time from left to right. A value
byte 80 stands left of 01.
• The first line describes the width and the height of a picture. Width and height are 16 bit
values each in the Big-Endian format.
• Also if the width is not devidable by 8, it is required that the missing pixel must be
transmitted.
Each line will be transmitted with following values:
• Optional repetition factor, caused by 00 00 FF xx, whereby xx describes the amount of
copies of the current line.
• Picture data - whereby different descriptions are optional possible:
a: Zerobytes are displayed through the amount of bytes.Valid input: 00 to FF.
b: Blackbytes (FF) can also be described through the amount of bytes, beginning
from 81 (81 means 1 time FF, - valid values are 81 to FF ).
c: A directly encoded number of bytes starts with 80 - followed by the amount of data, i.e.
80 03 123456. The amout of transmitted bytes can be between 01 and 7F.
d: A repeated pattern of arbitrary bytes can be initiated with a sequence 00 nn xx, which
means that xx bytes will be inserted nn times.
Example: 00 04 AA generates AAAAAAAA.
```

Comment: My first intuition would be to convert the image to a byte-array, and then convert the byte array to hex-string. Would that be a suitable solution?

Comment: @LarsKristensen I did try that.  I attached the code I threw together.  It resulted in 1088 lines of code, which is significantly more than what they generated.

Comment: What part of an Image is accepted as input. All of it? Headers and other format-specific definitions included? Or just the color table(s) and pixel mapping(s)?

Comment: @Jimi Ive added some clips from the docs, although at this point it may be too much into the weeds for SO >.<

Comment: Definitely. I think it could be useful to convert all sources to a single type of image: => Load from Stream -> Save to a MemoryStream in BMP format. Go through the tables following the manual instructions. BMP because is quite simple and well documented. If the Images must be sent in B&W, you could pre-filter with a B&W matrix. This will further simplify the task. For a simple B&W convertion see this: [Replacing Colour Of An Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47521672/replacing-colour-of-an-image?answertab=active#tab-top). GIF is a good source candidate in this case. Simple palette.