# How to improve read tesseract accuracy in c#

Tags: c#, image-processing, tesseract, emgucv

I have try many method to improve my image to be read by tesseract so clearly. but i still get wrong result and i need to know what method that i need to do to fix this one. Thankyou
[image: The result that i have now :]

Comment: Try a black and white conversion + [color inversion] + [threshold adjustment]. See the notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529000/7444103). You can also try to adjust the Gamma. See the Docs about the `ImageAttributes` class.

Comment: Thank you for the comment i already solve my problem but i have problem with "NIK" Line because font of the number have a diffrent and always fail to read by OCR @Jimi

Answer (score 0):

To increase the accuracy you need some working around
. Convert the image to black and white 
. Increase the contrast so the black is much more readable on the white. 
When you get the tesseract results you have to work on them
. For example in your results, on the first line you can see that after the column (:) you have the numbers. And when you take a look at the result  all the 4 are transformed into u, so you can write a function and base on some conditions like
-when is the same kind of document 
-when it must be a number
u is 4 (u->4) and so on. 
Tesseract is general purpose ocr engine so you have to work a little beat on the result to make it more specific to the type of document you reading.