# Read text block from capture screen shoot by Tesseract C# window form

Tags: c#, winforms, tesseract, read-text

Im try read text from bitmap(capture screen) by Tesseract using C#, but result wrong word language.
My code:

```
    Class TesseractApi{
    
            public static auto_login.text_rect get_all_text(Bitmap bitmp = null)
            {
                Bitmap bmp;
    
                if (bitmp != null)
                    bmp = bitmp;
                else bmp = ScreenShot.Capture();
    
                auto_login.text_rect results = new auto_login.text_rect();
                Tesseract.PageIteratorLevel myLevel = PageIteratorLevel.TextLine;
    
                using (var img = PixConverter.ToPix(bmp))
                {
                    using (var page = engine.Process(img))
                    {
                        using (var iter = page.GetIterator())
                        {
                            iter.Begin();
                            do
                            {
                                if (iter.TryGetBoundingBox(myLevel, out var rect))
                                {
                                    var curText = iter.GetText(myLevel).ToLower();
    
                                    results.Add(new auto_login.text_rect()
                                    {
                                        text = curText,
                                        x = rect.X1,
                                        y = rect.Y1
                                    });
    
                                }
                            } while (iter.Next(myLevel));
    
                            //iter.Dispose();
                            //page.Dispose();
                            img.Dispose();
                            bmp.Dispose();
                        }
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }
}
```

Calling...

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("test/screen.png");
text_rect text_arg = TesseractApi.get_all_text(bmp);
```

pic capture from screen
[image]

Result:

> anench
>
> 1.
>
> 1 .
>
> l ‘ ' 1”: ,_ c.
>
> wm63mm,”“mm, , y
>
> almweunnswwnedw! .
>
> (puddellhzslo-ne? aunnel 7
>
> . [puppet] n-s wowed om ' ; ,
>
> quppaqhasmmudchinnnl a 0 / v: ‘ \ 1mm -
>
> if f / - ‘ j 1 ' ‘ ., aurlnoiennovshndwnmum v
>
> . \ i 4 "mm ‘
>
> ‘ ‘ i ‘,/ \ \ dwnoc-lermwunnmn i
>
> ‘ em mum i

i want get word "**WAVE**", and get position Bound

see pic word "**WAVE**"

[image]

what is wrong with my code

Comment: The first thing you have to do is to avoid the JPEG format for this, it's not really its thing. Take the screenshot and save it as PNG or TIFF. Then, try to convert to grayscale or black and white. Try the method here: [Replacing Color of an Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529000/7444103), using the inverted Matrix: I suppose, given the Image you're showing, that it can work better (the words will become almost all black and the rest will drift towards white).

Comment: Also try a Grayscale conversion; see the `ToGrayScale` method shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61584671/7444103) -- About the B&W conversion, try with a low threshold (10), it will increase the white areas and make the text pop.

Comment: tesseract will be happy if you feed a black-n-white image. This might help you https://medium.com/cashify-engineering/improve-accuracy-of-ocr-using-image-preprocessing-8df29ec3a033

Comment: Thanks everybody comment, i have solved this my question.
1. we should be define picture "WAVE" by icon 10x10
2. get position X-Y then capture area timer number
3. we clear color by SetPixel orange to black