# How can I read pixels from jpg file into a picturebox?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ReadImage()
    {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(@"d:\test.jpg");

        var whitePixels = 0;
        var blackPixels = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < image.Width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < image.Height; j++)
            {
                Color pixel = image.GetPixel(i, j);

                // if it's a white color then just debug...
                if (pixel == Color.White)
                    whitePixels++;
                else
                    blackPixels++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to display the white pixels and black pixels in a PictureBox to show the drawn image from the file. How can I do it? And is there a way to do it also in 3d in the PictureBox?

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do.  I ~think~ you simply want to create a NEW bitmap of the same size, then clear it to white.  Now draw a 1x1 rectangle at (i,j) whenever you find a non-white pixel?  ...but what the heck do you mean by "3d" in this case?

Comment: If you want to turn an Image to Black&White, you can use a ColorMatrix. See here: [Replacing Colour Of An Image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47529000/7444103), for example. If you instead want to *manually* (based on custom criteria) turn all pixels that are not exactly white to black, use [Bitmap.LockBits()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.lockbits) to parse the image data and write the values you want into a copy of the original Bitmap.